# SCCM schedule a Logon script like

Tags: scripting, operating-system, sccm

I need to create a scheduled logon script that will be running on each logon (Until I choose to stop it) just like in GPO but with SCCM 
is that possible? the script must run as admin

Answer (score 0):

Well the options are there. You can configure a Program to run 
"Only when a user is logged on"
"Run with administrative rights" in the "Environment" properties of the program and to "Run once for every user who logs on" in the "Advanced" settings. Then in the deployment "Scheduling" settings create an assignment and choose "Assign immediately after this event" "Log on" with Rerun behavior set to "Always rerun program"

In theory this should do the trick. That being said I never tried it nor would i necessarily trust the SCCM to be super reliable with such settings.

May I ask why GPOs are not an option? There are also less awkward workarounds such as just using SCCM to write the reg keys a GPO would set fo a start script, creating a scheduled task with the System account, triggered at log on, or maybe if it fits the description in some way using sccm configuration baselines instead of a program.